# splunk regex issue

Tags: splunk, splunk-calculation

How can we write regex for below?

```
CEF:0|Incapsula|SIEMintegration|1|1|Normal|0| fileId=465000430130063349
```

Here I want to extract only `0` placed between `||` just before `fileId`.

Answer (score 2):

In the following regex we have:

- a named capture group called "myField" that grabs a number `(?<myField>\d)`
- that is in between the `|` character, escaped as: `\|`
- followed by an optional space (your example had a space between `|` and `fileId`): `\s?`
- and then the text fileId: `fileId`

Putting it all together:

```
\|(?<myField>\d)\|\s?fileId
```

So you should be able to apply the regex in Splunk with:

```
| rex field=_raw "\|(?<myField>\d)\|\s?fileId"
```

And then use the `myField`. Obviously, rename to whatever makes sense for you, and target the appropriate field if not `_raw`